# Report Server issue. Almost on every day we have to restart the services of Report Server

Tags: sqlreportingservice

In Secondary DB server we are facing a Report Server issue. Almost on every day we have to restart the services of Report Server. Some times through this also we are not able to resolve this issue. We have restart the DB server only, because we are not able restart the services of Reporting Services.

Please suggest, How do I render report without restarting the server again and again?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the issue you're seeing? (Restarting the services is the fix - and a problematic one at best - but it's not the issue itself). What happens if you don't restart?

Comment: Also, when did the issue start? What version of SSRS and SQL Server are you running?